# Paypal Express Style/Look

Tags: magento, paypal

We are setting up the paypal express payment option for our magento store,
and found out that where are 2 'styles':

Old style:
http://dropproxy.com/f/C0E

And New style:
http://dropproxy.com/f/C0F

Which setting determines that?

We currently have 'old style' and want to change to 'new style'.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: Ask someone @ PayPal. (And check the URL parameters, but...). FYI it may be something you can't control: PayPal is continually improving their UI, and the second one may be something that is in testing and (if it proves out superior) will be rolled out to everyone; you would not have to take any action; your customers would just get the improvements as PayPal rolls them out.

Comment: @geewiz is correct.  You can't control those pages.  The reason you see both at various times is because PayPal is split testing them to see which one converts better in order to help make improvements with the new pages.

Comment: Ok, guys thank you for your replies. You were much more helpful/knowledgable than papal support.